# How can I compare this datetime from the MySQL database with now?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I compare this datetime from the MySQL database with now?

I sent the date in the database record using the MySQL function now() and was trying to detect records that were more than 30 days old.

```
if (date_diff($myrow["LastLogin"], time()) > -30) {
  }
```

`$myrow["LastLogin"]` does contain a valid value since i see it as text.  confirmed in the database it's a "datetime" type.

here's more of the code.

```
if ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result_set)) { 

  do {
      if (date_diff($myrow["LastLogin"], getdate()) > -30) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $myrow["PCName"] . '&nbsp;</td>';
        echo "<td>" . $myrow["LastLogin"] . '&nbsp;</td>';
        echo "</tr>\n";
      }
  } while ($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result_set));  
}
```

thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do it in your query, not in the code.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE LastLogin < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it server side via

```
SELECT * FROM logins WHERE LastLogin < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

If you need to do it client side, it might be easier to use `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` which returns an integer:

```
SELECT l.*,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(LastLogin) AS LastLogin_i FROM logins l
```

If neither of these suits your needs, you could convert the string returned by `LastLogin` using `strtotime()`:

```
lastLogin_i = strtotime($myrow["LastLogin"]);
```

Comment: strtodate? the php dunction date() can convert a unix_timestamp to a readable date, and strtotime can convert a readable date to a unixtimestamp

Answer (score 1):

This query will delete records where the lastlogin value is more than 30 days old.

```
Delete from table where ((now() - lastlogin) > (30*24*60*60))
```